# Hamachi not getting properly installed

Tags: installation, hamachi

We have been trying to install/uninstall Hamachi for a couple times, but I keep seeing the issue that, after reboot the machine

1. Hamachi is not power on automatically
2. When trying to power it on, it'll ask for a new client name
3. Once the client name is provided, it'll get a different IP and because of which we will have to rejoin our network again and lost the earlier IP.

We did some investigation and found out that few installation path were just wrong

1. In registry, the EngineConfigDir is set to be C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\AppData\Local\LogMeIn Hamachi, but actually there is no such path as all on the machine, we only see C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\Local Settings\Application Data or C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\Application Data on the machine, and none of them has the LogMeIn Hamachi subdirectory found
2. Same to the above, in UI Advanced Settings, the log path is set to be C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\AppData\Local\LogMeIn Hamachi\h2-engine.log, but we were not able to locate the file at all

This is a Windows XP machine, and we were trying to install Hamachi version 2.2.0.58.

Has anyone see this issue before and let us know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the directories manually:

C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\AppData\Local\LogMeIn Hamachi

You'll need to un-hide the operating system folders.

Then it kept its Hamachi IP and didn't require registration again after a restart.